# How to multiply to columns value and group by another columns and return a list of object using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table in db with columns Id, Code, Param_1 and Param_2. I want to multiply Param_1 and Param_2, Grouping by Code and returns Code and Sum of Param_1 * Param_2 as new object using Linq. For example, let's assume that as it appears below:

```
Id | Code | Param_1 | Param_2
-----------------------------
1  | Abc1 |   2     |   3    
2  | Abc1 |   1     |   4    
3  | Abc2 |   5     |   7
```

And i want to get result as shown below

```
new List<TestObj>
{
   new TestObj 
   {
      Code = "Abc1",
      Value = 10 // 2 * 3 + 1 * 4 
   }
   new TestObj 
   {
      Code = "Abc2",
      Value = 35 // 5 * 7
   }
}
```

Comment: And have you tried to get a result?

Comment: I have not idea to trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query group by the rows on column **Code** after that it first multiplies the **param_1** and **param_2** columns and then adds the result.

```
List<Test> temp = new List<Test>();
            temp.Add(new Test(1, "Abc1", 2, 3));
            temp.Add(new Test(2, "Abc1", 1, 4));
            temp.Add(new Test(3, "Abc2", 5, 7));

            var q = from t in temp
                    group t by t.Code into g
                    select new { Code = g.Key, Value = g.Select(p => new { Code = p.Code, Val = p.Param_1 * p.Param_2 } ).Sum(a => a.Val)};

            foreach (var item in q)
            {
               
                Console.WriteLine($"Code: {item.Code} , Value: {item.Value}");
                
            }
```

Here is how my output looks

```
Code : Abc1 , Value : 10
Code : Abc2 , Value : 35
```

Comment: Plese can u help me to convert this linq to Sql Query? I am new here

Comment: Here is the equivalent MySQL query : SELECT *,SUM(param_1 * param_2) FROM Test
group by code

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple to get the required result. Please see my explanations in the code below inline. For more info I would recommend to read some articles or books about LINQ.

```
    public class DTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public int Param_1 { get; set; }
        public int Param_2 { get; set; }
    }

    public class TestObj
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

        class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testData = new List<DTO>
            {
                new DTO{ Id = 1, Code = "Abc1", Param_1 = 2, Param_2 = 3 },
                new DTO{ Id = 2, Code = "Abc1", Param_1 = 1, Param_2 = 4 },
                new DTO{ Id = 3, Code = "Abc2", Param_1 = 5, Param_2 = 7 }
            };

            /*In select statement we are performing multiplication for Param_1 and Param_1.
             * As a result we transforming records from this view
             * 1  | Abc1 |   2     |   3 
             * 2  | Abc1 |   1     |   4 
             * 3  | Abc2 |   5     |   7 
             * to this
             * | Abc1 |   6
             * | Abc1 |   4
             * | Abc2 |   35
             */
            var t = testData.Select(a => new
                                    {
                                        Code = a.Code,
                                        Value = a.Param_1 * a.Param_2
                                    })
                            /*Grouping statement allows us to group records by Code and get this result:
                             * | Abc1 |   6
                             *            4
                             * | Abc2 |   35
                             */
                            .GroupBy(a => a.Code)
                            /*And finally we can map the result of grouping to the required object and get
                             * this result:
                             * | Abc1 |   10
                             * | Abc2 |   35
                             */
                            .Select(g => new TestObj {
                                Code = g.Key,
                                Value = g.Sum(v => v.Value)
                            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank u very much but i get answer from upper comment